# Ruby on rails command does not trigger any action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not to ruby on rails, and I'm setting up my first application, according to a textbook (Ruby 4 in Rails). No action is triggered, When typing the command:

$ rails generate scaffold purchase name:string cost:decimal

Can anyone help me resolved this?

I installed Ruby and Rails, newest versions and then did the following steps before typing the mentioned command.

1. $ rails new things_i_bought
2. $ cd things_i_bought
3. $ rails server

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  We could use a little more information in order to help.  When you say 'No action is triggered', what do you mean?  Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
$ rails server
```

You're starting the server. You don't to want do that when working from the command line.

Hit Ctrl-C to stop the server, then run your scaffold command.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. I had forgotten to enter the folder of the application when performing the commands.

Comment: Ha! Good to hear. Have fun on the new adventure!